Importing error "cannot import name 'check_and_transform_label_format' from 'art.utils'"
I am trying to use the adversarial robustness toolbox (ART) library in Python to excute  an attack on an AI model.
from art.estimators.classification import SklearnClassifier
from art.attacks.evasion import ZooAttack

I faced an a problem of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'art.attacks' and I solve it by pip install adversarial-robustness-toolbox
I encountered another problem in art.estimators.classification :
cannot import name 'check_and_transform_label_format' from 'art.utils'
